# How to track received notification in iOS and Android using FCM?

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are sending Push Notification through the Server.

I wanted to track the event, how many notification were received on iOS and Android.

1. Is there any way to get this number with notification info?
2. Is there any delegate method or any way in iOS that can confirm that we have received push notification in respective of  notification clicked or not?

.

Comment: check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=android

Answer (score 1):

In android, there is a method to intercept the FCM notification you can find the implementation in this [thread](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive.).

Each device notification is received by this callback so you can create some API or some logic to get the acknowledgement back.

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    Log.d(TAG, "From: ${remoteMessage.from}")
    // do the logic here.    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS you can use

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

To make a call to your server and tell your server that the notification was received.

Another solution would be to use FCM Rest to send the notifications

`POST /v1/{parent=projects/*}/messages:send`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest

If you include google analytics the Cloud messaging dashboard will have all the info if the user has provided permissions such as IDFA.